# Solving for $A_1$ in $A_1+A_2=\arctan\left(\frac{P_{1x}+m\cdot \sin(A_1+A_a)-P_{3y}}{P_{1y}+m\cdot \cos(A_1+A_a)-P_{3x}}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve this trig equation for $A_1$ but I'm not sure if it is solvable (at least with my level of skill). $P_1$ and $P_3$ are both individual 2D points and $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_a$ are degree angles.$$A_1+A_2=\arctan\left(\frac{P_{1x}+m\cdot \sin(A_1+A_a)-P_{3y}}{P_{1y}+m\cdot \cos(A_1+A_a)-P_{3x}}\right)$$
After attempting to solve it I got to this level and didn't know how to further simplify the equation.
$$\tan(A_1)=\frac{\sin(A_2)u-\cos(A_2)v}{\sin(A_2)v-\cos(A_2)u}
\\where\\
u=P_{1x}+m\cdot \sin(A_1+A_a)-P_{3y}
\\
v=P_{1y}+m\cdot \cos(A_1+A_a)-P_{3x}$$
If this equation can be solved I would like to know how to solve these in the future, but if it cannot, I would like to know why and how to determine why it can't be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking for some help on Reddit, [u/Theowoll](https://www.reddit.com/user/Theowoll/) solved this equation using [Tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution). Here is the work he showed:

Setting
$$
Y = \dfrac{P_{1y}-P_{3y}}{m_2}
\\\
X = \dfrac{P_{1x}-P_{3x}}{m_2}
\\\
\alpha = A_1+A_2
\\\
\beta = A_2-A_a
$$
Taking the tangent on both sides of the equation gives
$$
\sin\beta=Y\cos\alpha-X\sin\alpha
$$
And after some simplifications using
$$
t=\tan\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)
\\\
\sin\alpha=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}
\\\
\cos\alpha=\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}
$$
You will find the solutions
$$
\alpha = 2\arctan(\dfrac{-X\pm \sqrt{X^2+Y^2-\sin^2(\beta)}}{Y+\sin\beta})
$$